# Passwords in a LAMP installation on Debian

Tags: apache-httpd, mysql, php5

In a locally installed a LAMP stack, where are the passwords stored? If there is more than one, I only have the MySQL password from the previous installation, but the new one uses the same. Don't PHP5 and Apache2 require a password? Do they have a standard password?

After purge and re-install the passwords were not reset.

Answer (score 1):

The only passwords involved will be the user account password you use to log in and upload files, etc. and then 2 mysql passwords, one for the root user (DIFFERENT from the Linux root user) and one for whatever user you connect to the mysql database as.

Note that you can set up a "www-data" user in mysql with no password and only allow it to connect from localhost, and Apache/PHP will use that by default IF you do not provide any other information.